# Adobe indesign merge from code

Tags: c#, adobe-indesign

I have created a webform where a user enters some values. I also have an Indesign template.

Is it possible to do a data merge from code (C#)? I would create a comma delimited string as you normally would with a CSV. And then send it to the template somehow to get a finished result in PDF. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can do a data merge of comma or tab delimited files pretty easily in InDesign.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6c3ca.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with doing a data merge in "InDesign." Your answer does not answer how to do this with C#. Please read the question.